# Can you make boolean expressions in xparse?

Tags: macros, xparse, etoolbox

I have a preamble I use on my assignments containing the following command using `xparse`:

```latex
\ProvideDocumentCommand{\integral}{s m m e{_^}}{%
    \int%
    \IfValueT{#4}{_{#4}}%
    \IfValueT{#5}{^{#5}}%
    \IfBooleanTF{#1}{\parenth*{#3}}{#3}%
    \odif{#2}%
}
```

It isn't important, but the commands `\parenth*{}` is my own, and `\odif{}` is from the [derivative](https://ctan.org/pkg/derivative) package.

Basically, this code does the following:

```latex
\integral{z}{f(z)}_a^b
\integral{z}{f(z)}_C
```

becomes:

[image: code example]

I want to change how this code behaves so that, when argument #4 is given, but not #5, it uses `\oint` in place of `\int` on the first line of the command's body. And, in every other case, it should remain as is, with the `\int` functionality.

I know that with `etoolbox` there are commands such as `\ifboolexpr{expr}{true}{false}`, but I am not sure how to use it properly if I do need to use it. My closest example is

```latex
\ProvideDocumentCommand{\integral}{s m m e{_^}}{%
    \ifboolexpr{bool {#4} nand bool {#5}}{\oint}{\int}%
    \IfValueT{#4}{_{#4}}%
    \IfValueT{#5}{^{#5}}%
    \IfBooleanTF{#1}{\parenth*{#3}}{#3}%
    \odif{#2}%
}
```

However, since #4 and #5 aren't booleans, this doesn't work. I am unsure what the cleanest way is to achieve my goal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply make use of already known `\IfValue(TF)`. In order to achieve `A && !B`, one can nest the condition the following way

```
\IfValueTF{#5}{\int}{\IfValueTF{#4}{\oint}{\int}}
```

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{derivative}

\ProvideDocumentCommand{\integral}{s m m e{_^}}{%
    \IfValueTF{#5}{\int}{\IfValueTF{#4}{\oint}{\int}}
    \IfValueT{#4}{_{#4}}%
    \IfValueT{#5}{^{#5}}%
    \IfBooleanTF{#1}{\parenth*{#3}}{#3}%
    \odif{#2}%
}

\begin{document}

\[
\integral{z}{f(z)}_a^b
\qquad
\integral{z}{f(z)}_C
\qquad
\integral{z}{f(z)}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Ahhh! You're totally right, I didn't even consider that. That is much simpler! Thanks a lot :D